# PHP: Get md5 hash of string + integer addition?

Tags: php, md5

I'm debugging some older PHP code. The original programmer included an operation which I think is intended to generate a random id string, by adding two random `integers` to a `string` and passing it to the `md5()` method, which seems to break the program:

```
$id = md5($someString + rand(0, 9999999) + rand(0, 9999999));
```

Passing each part of the argument to the method separately works as expected:

```
$id = md5($someString);      // Works fine
$id = md5(rand(0, 9999999)); // Works fine
```

Joining the arguments together as a `string` before passing it also works:

```
$randomInt_0 = rand(0, 9999999);
$randomInt_1 = rand(0, 9999999);
$id          = md5($someString . $randomInt_0 . $randomInt_1); // Works fine
```

Why is the original code not working (I assume it did at some point)?
Might passing a `string` + `integer` addition to `md5()` cause a problem?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/em1rk concatenation in PHP is the `.` not the `+` Just like you used in the lines that work :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly "concatenating" with + would have "worked" in legacy versions, where a non-numeric string would have been silently coerced to an integer (0). https://3v4l.org/vNSol#v5.0.5 ... which is probably not what was intended, but it passed as a meaningless `0 + rand + rand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have "worked" in PHP<8 by implied conversion from string to integer for `$someString` according to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

eg:

- `"1234"` to `1234`
- `"1234foo"` to `1234` plus a notice.
- `"foo"` to `0` plus a warning.

Post PHP8 the second is now a warning, and the third is an error.

You can make this bad code work with an explicit cast:

```
md5((int)$someString + rand(0, 9999999) + rand(0, 9999999));
```

But given the context it would be less incorrect to write it as concatenation instead:

```
md5($someString . rand(0, 9999999) . rand(0, 9999999));
```

Since this is probably for some sort of unique token, and preserving the input string as a string and not `0` would put more entropy in the token.